# How to incorporate this function into another function in R?

Tags: r, function

I have a function (`centroid`) that calculates the centroids (means) across points. I'm trying to incorporate it into the `k_means` function instead of using 'mean'. Replacing 'mean' with `centroid` returns an error: `do.call("cbind", pointList) : second argument must be a list`. My data is in matrix form with multiple columns, so this may be the issue. Can anyone suggest a fix where I can incorporate the `centroid` function into the `k_means` function, instead of using 'mean'?

```
centroid <- function(pointList) {
  rowMeans(do.call("cbind", pointList))
}

k_means = function(x, centers, distFun) {
  prevClusters = NULL
  prevCenters = NULL
  
  repeat {
    distsToCenters = distFun(x, centers)
    clusters = apply(distsToCenters, 1L, which.min)
    centers = apply(x, 2L, tapply, clusters, mean) # If I replace 'mean' here with 'centroid', error comes
    if (identical(prevClusters, clusters)) break
    
    prevClusters = clusters
    prevCenters = centers
  }
  
  list(clusters = clusters, centers = centers)
}
```

Comment: So e.g. if you had a list: `list(c(0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1), c(0, 1, 0))`, the centroids would be `0, 1/3, 1/3` because it takes the mean across the corresponding elements in a list. The data would be in matrix form instead of list.

Comment: Have you tried converting the `matrix` to `dataframe`? You should pass the error since `dataframe` is also a list.